# jQuery UI Slider Range incorrect max value for fraction step

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to make a jQuery UI slider range with the following options

```
min: 0,
max: 100,
step: 0.01
```

The range works for all the values except for the last one, which becomes `99.99000000000001`. I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0vxrxL1/2/) to recreate the issue. The behavior is different for the max value 50 and 100. Any help would be really appreciated.

PS: I am using jQuery UI v1.11.2 as in WP version 4.1.1. If I use jQuery UI version 1.11.3, then the same resolves. ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u0tq9mcf/1/)).

Comment: [Is floating point math broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k0vxrxL1/4/

Comment: I have seen the link. What I would like right now is any direction to get it implemented through current version of jQuery UI (1.11.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set max: 50.001, max: 100.001 :)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! I was looking for something like this (a hackish implementation that would just work until WP updates its library).